# undefined reference to address even though there's no reference to it on the line mentioned

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm getting the following error:

```
build/main.o:source/main.s:91: undefined reference to `addr_r'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

from this code:

```
82] @ Register Aliases for subroutines
83] addr_r  .req    r4
84]
85] write_latch:
86]     mov     fp, sp              @ save position in calling code
87]     PUSH    {r4-r10}            @ preserve variable registers
89]         @ do stuff here later
90]     POP     {r4-r10}            @ restore variable registers
91]     bx      lr                  @ return to position in calling code
```

Im using ARMv7 on a Raspberry Pi 3 running rasbian. Can anyone help explain why or how to fix it?

Comment: Labels must be followed by colons in GNU assembler syntax.

Comment: @fuz : .`.req` is a GNU assembler ARM directive that does register aliasing and doesn't require a colon as per the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Very weird.  Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem wasn't on line 91 at all, the problem was the following line in a different subroutine:

```
ldr r0, =addr_r     @ address for GPFSEL{n}
```

I was refering to an aliased register as a label, changed it to:

```
mov r0, addr_r      @ address for GPFSEL{n}
```

and that fixed the problem! :D

Comment: I would suggest you either to not use aliases for registers at all, or at least put original register into the alias, like `addr_r4`, because your alias makes it impossible to see which register is being used, which is important to see quickly when reviewing/bug hunting. Without that I personally would be very prone to re-use the `r4` for something else, as I would forget after few days it was already "allocated" for `addr_r`.